# Prove the following statement by combinatorial argument.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Prove the following statement by combinatorial argument:-
$({n \choose0}+{n \choose1})×({n \choose1}+{n \choose2})×\cdots×({n \choose n-1}+{n \choose n})= \frac{{n \choose0}{n \choose1}{n \choose2}\cdots{n \choose n}}{n!}×(1+n)^{n} $

Well I found this question from my friend, a math lover and me too.. i thought that I could do the sum but it was confusing my mind.  I am weak in making combinatorial argument so I need a help to withstand the problem so I posted here.

Comment: The series is looking like simple but my mind cannot find a solution of it. I had proves the statement by algebraically but I cannot find the answer by combinatorial argument. Please help

Comment: I think the denominator should be $n!$ instead of $\binom n1$. That makes the $n=3$ case come out right, and it also follows from @Aqua's algebraic answer.

Comment: $n!$ means ${n \choose 1}$. Isnt it??

Comment: No, $n!$ means "$n$ [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)", i.e. the product of all natural numbers less than or equal to $n$.

Comment: I mean by algebraically it is same... There is a twist in the question... As I consulted my teacher .... As ${n \choose 1}$ must be written as $n!$ and then it need to be interpreted.

Comment: No, it is also not algebraically the same. $\binom n1=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!1!}=n$.

Comment: Yaaa... Sorry....

Comment: Are you aware that you can edit the question? There's an "edit" link underneath it.

Comment: Ok... I did it..

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

You can use  $${n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k} = {n+1\choose k}$$

and a fact that $${n+1\choose k}= {(n+1)!\over k!(n+1-k)!} $$ $$={n+1\over n+1-k }\cdot  {n!\over k!(n-k)!} = {n+1\over n+1-k } {n\choose k}$$

Comment: Please explain it by giving argument.. like boxes and balls.. etc

Comment: I could not get you. Can I have the combinatorial argument?

Comment: Consult the wikipedia

Comment: This is not a combinatorial argument; it's algebra. ("Consult Wikipedia" is also not a combinatorial argument.)

Comment: OK @joriki......Will you give it?

Comment: I don't have one either :-)

Answer (score -1):

What about the following for a combinatorial argument.
Let the following function be defined
$$f:\mathbb{S}_n\times \binom{[n+1]}{1}\times \cdots \times \binom{[n+1]}{n}\longrightarrow \binom{[n]}{1}\times \cdots \times \binom{[n]}{n}\times [n+1]^{[n]},$$
where $[n]=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\},$ $\mathbb{S}_n$ means the group of permutations in $n$ letters and $\binom{[n]}{k}=\{ A\subseteq [n]:|A|=k \}.$

 Such that $f(\pi ,A_1,\cdots ,A_n)=(A_1\cap [n],\cdots A_n\cap [n],f)$ and $f(x)=n+1$ if $n+1\in A_x$ and $f(x)=\pi _{x-g(x)}$ where $g(x)=| \{ i\in [n]:n+1\in A_i \} |.$
So, basically, this is a bijection because it has an inverse (mainly adding $n+1$ to the sets whenever you see an $n+1$ given by $f.$) and the result follows if you know that $\binom{[n+1]}{k}\equiv \binom{[n]}{k}+\binom{[n]}{k-1}$(Pascals identity.)

Comment: I could not get you. I think you are doing by functional statement.

Comment: I don't know what functional statement means. This is a bijective proof.